# How to remove part of a widget in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, web, hyperlink, widget

I want to remove these three links from my web page:

- RSS за публикациите
- RSS за коментарите
- WordPress.org

I have made my web site con WordPress.

Here it is: http://www.podkrepa-plovdiv.com/%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8/

Answer (score 1):

More information is needed.  Is the site hosted on WordPress or on your own self-hosted site?  (Such as GoDaddy or 1and1).  If it is the former, it is almost impossible to change plugins but if it's self hosted you should be able to edit the plugin that is creating the links.

Comment: It's self hosted . But how can I remove these three links?

Comment: Is it a plugin that is creating the links on the side of the site or coded into the web page itself?

Comment: That shouldn't be too hard to remove.  Are you able to put the code on here so I can see what needs to be removed?